# Is there a simple way to create a time lapse video with Canon Powershot?

Tags: canon, android, powershot

I have a Canon PowerShot SX 540 HS.

Is there a simple way to create a time lapse video?

I'm fine using an Android app for this if required.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do a timelapse.

Get a tripod and mount your camera.

Get a chair and count some numbers and shoot. A clock is useful.

Repeat the shoot for some minutes.

Now use an editing software to convert the image sequence to video. One useful program is VirtualDub.

Comment: Yes, you are right. This works. But since most cameras support timelapse, this way feels too complicated today.

Answer (score 0):

I found one possible solution. The "Canon Hacker Development Kit" can be used and you can install an alternative firmware: http://chdk.wikia.com/wiki/SX530HS

.... But I am unsure if I want to go this way. If possible, I would like to use a more "official" way to get time lapse videos working.

I have a SX540, not a 530, this is one of several uncertainties why I would like to go a save way.

Comment: Do not use this software for different type of camera, this can lead to brick.

Comment: @RomeoNinov ok, now I have a new question: https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/95479/chdk-no-official-builds-are-available-for-this-camera (How to get CHDK working on this camera?)

Comment: guettli, unfortunately this is not so easy. Please check the answer of Philip Kendall

Comment: @RomeoNinov CHDK won't brick the camera because it doesn't modify the on-camera firmware. All changes are in memory only. Just turn the camera off, then back on.