# Can I get the Canon hacker development kit to work for a camera that has no official CHDK builds?

Tags: canon, powershot, chdk

I tried to find a matching [CHDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIGIC#Custom_firmware) version for my Canon PowerShot SX540 HS.

The tool [ACID](http://www.zenoshrdlu.com/acid/acid.html) tells me:

`No official builds are available for this camera`

See

[image: acid-result]

What could I do to get CHDK working on this camera?

Comment: Related: [Is there a way to get Magic Lantern for the Canon T6i (750D)?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/71329)

Answer (score 6):

Unless you're a developer with experience in reverse engineering firmware and prepared to put a *lot* of time and effort in, you can't use CHDK on your camera. As you can see from the [CHDK developers page](http://chdk.wikia.com/wiki/For_Developers), the SX540 HS is colour coded black, which means:

> Black - neither original firmware nor firmware dump is available

or in other words, it's not even possible to begin development of CHDK on the SX540 HS at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

You can encourage development by providing developers with a firmware dump. The following resources may be helpful.

- CHDK Wiki: [Obtaining a firmware dump](https://chdk.fandom.com/wiki/Obtaining_a_firmware_dump).
- CHDK Wiki: [Canon Basic/Scripts/Dumper](https://chdk.fandom.com/wiki/Canon_Basic/Scripts/Dumper)
- CHDK Wiki: [Udumper](https://chdk.fandom.com/wiki/Udumper)